# ElasticSearch get last n distinct records

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to implement a search query over records stored in elasticsearch.
The record structure looks something like this.

```
   {
    "_index" : "box_info_store",
    "_type" : "boxes",
    "_id" : "pWjQLWkBIJk0ORjd0X2P",
    "_score" : null,    
    "_source" : {
      "transactionID" : "60ab66cf24c9924f562bf1a2b5d92305d0a6",
      "boxNumber" : "Box3",
      "createDate" : "2013-09-17T00:00:00",
      "itemNumber" : "Item1",
      "address" : "Sample Address"
    }
  }
```

one box can contain multiple items. For example Box3 can have Item1, Item2 and Item3. So in elasticsearch i will have 3 different documents. Also at the same time, same box and same item can also exist but with different address. The transactionID may or maynot be the same for these documents.

My requirement is to fetch last n recent and distinct transactionIDs, along with their records.

I tried following query to fetch last 7 distinct transactionIDs

```
GET /box_info_store/boxes/_search?size=7
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
         {"match":{"boxNumber":"Box3"}},
         {"match":{"itemNumber":"Item1"}}
         ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "createDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_transactions": {
      "terms": { "field": "transactionID"}
    }
  }
}
```

This fetched me last 7 documents where boxNumber is Box3 and itemNumber is Item1, but not 7 distinct transactionIDs, two out of these seven documents have the same transactionID(both having separate address though).
But my requirement is to get 7 distinct transactionIds, no matter how many document it returns.

Hope i was able to explain myself.
Appreciate any kind of help here

Thanks

------Edited @gaurav9620, i ran the first query and got count as 32, then i ran the second query with distinct count as 3  i got the following result

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 32,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "box_info_store",
        "_type" : "boxes",
        "_id" : "RWjRLWkBIJk0ORjdEX-L",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "transactionID" : "3087e106244f6247a5290fb21ce64254529c",
          "boxNumber" : "Box3",
          "createDate" : "2017-11-15T00:00:00",
          "itemNumber" : "Item1",
          "address" : "sampleAddress12",
        },
        "sort" : [
          1510704000000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "box_info_store",
        "_type" : "boxes",
        "_id" : "MGjQLWkBIJk0ORjdwX0M",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "transactionID" : "60ab66cf24c9924f562bf1a2b5d92305d0a6",
          "boxNumber" : "Box3",
          "createDate" : "2016-04-03T00:00:00",
          "itemNumber" : "Item1",
          "address" : "sampleAddress321",
        },
        "sort" : [
          1459641600000
        ]
      },
      ..........
      ..........
      ..........
      {
        "_index" : "box_info_store",
        "_type" : "boxes",
        "_id" : "AGjRLWkBIJk0ORjdK4CJ",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "transactionID" : "3087e106244f6247a5290fb21ce64254529c",
          "boxNumber" : "Box3",
          "createDate" : "1996-02-16T00:00:00",
          "itemNumber" : "Item1",
          "address" : "sampleAddress4324",
        },
        "sort" : [
          824428800000
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "unique_transactions" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 16,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "3087e106244f6247a5290fb21ce64254529c",
          "doc_count" : 6
        },
        {
          "key" : "27c5f3422f4482495d29e7b2c15c0e311743",
          "doc_count" : 5
        },
        {
          "key" : "c40e53212e74e24bf02a5bd2b134cf92bffb",
          "doc_count" : 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size which you have used : **represents** number of raw documents that are retrieved.

If your case what you need to do is :

1. Mention  size as 0 -> which will return you no raw documents
2. Include a size parameter in aggregation which will return you unique 7 ids.

   GET /box_info_store/boxes/_search?size=7
   {
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "match": {
               "boxNumber": "Box3"
             }
           },
           {
             "match": {
               "itemNumber": "Item1"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     },
     "sort": [
       {
         "createDate": {
           "order": "desc"
         }
       }
     ],
     "aggs": {
       "distinct_transactions": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "transactionID",
           "size": 7
         }
       }
     }
   }

**EDIT-------------------------------------**

First fire this query

```
GET /box_info_store/boxes/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "boxNumber": "Box3"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "itemNumber": "Item1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here you will find total number of documents matching your query which you can set as **n**
After this fire your query as below

```
GET /box_info_store/boxes/_search?size=**n**
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "boxNumber": "Box3"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "itemNumber": "Item1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "createDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_transactions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "transactionID",
        "size": NUMBER_OF_UNIQUE_TRANSACTION_IDS_TO_BE_FETCHED
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @gaurav9620, using this i am able to get the distinct transactionIDs along with their doc_count. but not the document related to that IDs. How can i get those documents too. do i need to call again and fetch documents for those ids?

Comment: Just increase the size mentioned at the top from 0 to the number of documents you want to fetch

Comment: if i make the aggregation size as 3, it returns 3 transactionIDs, these 3 transactionIDs can belong to n number of documents with same box and item but different address, i need to fetch all those. Thus i will not know the outer size value. also if i don't give outer size value, then it is returning all the documents with box3 and item1, irrespective of those 3 distinct transactionIDs

Comment: thanks a lot for the update, i have updated my question , can you please assist further

Comment: Also I noticed, that when i do order by create date , the latest 3 transactionIDs, that i get are                                         3087e106244f6247a5290fb21ce64254529c
60ab66cf24c9924f562bf1a2b5d92305d0a6
f249e7bb2b35f24857288b9228cdc71ac520,                                                   
   but the aggregation query returns 3087e106244f6247a5290fb21ce64254529c
27c5f3422f4482495d29e7b2c15c0e311743
c40e53212e74e24bf02a5bd2b134cf92bffb,                                                     shouldn't the aggregation query return the first set?